# Error when deploying react project using Vercel CLI

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I was trying to deploy a react project to vercel by using vercel cli, when I tried to deploy and type vercel it shows me this error:

> Error! FetchError: request to https://api.vercel.com/v2/now/files failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 76.76.21.112:443

Comment: This could have been an issue with the network - is it happening consistently?

Comment: Have you tried doing vercel deploy insted of just vercel? It seems that solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to the old version of vercel CLI also.

For me using

```
npm i -g vercel@latest
```

helped me in fixing it.